# Setting the order of output for a table

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to generate a report and print the following table to a file in python:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
first_table_dict = {}
first_table_dict["Total agents"]        = len(agentUserIdDict)          
first_table_dict["Total users"]         = len(pure_user_dict)
first_table_dict["Users with agent"]    = len(pure_users_with_agents_dict)
first_table_dict["Users with invites"]  = len(user_id_invite_dict)
first_table_dict["RUURL accounts"]      = len(ruurl_set)
f.write(tabulate(first_table_dict.items(), headers = ["Category", "Total"]))
```

The output, however is:

```
Category              Total
------------------  -------
Users with invites    81533
Total users           90818
Users with agent      70060
Total agents          45571
RUURL accounts        81288
```

I understand the dictionaries are not ordered.  How do I get the list to be in the order I want?

Comment: By sorting it! See [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: [Tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) module seems to be support list of lists, why not use that instead of a dict?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary to be honest, I'm just more comfortable using the dictionary.  How would I append a list with a pair of items?

Comment: Unless you really want to use this `dict` later on there's no point in creating one, for a list something like: `your_list.append(["Total agents", len(agentUserIdDict)])`. Check the examples on the package's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you expect:

```
>>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}.items()
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

When in fact, sometimes you get

```
[('b', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

Why not just construct this data structure directly?

```
first_table = [
    ("Total agents"        , len(agentUserIdDict)),         
    ("Total users"         , len(pure_user_dict)), 
    ("Users with agent"    , len(pure_users_with_agents_dict)), 
    ("Users with invites"  , len(user_id_invite_dict)), 
    ("RUURL accounts"      , len(ruurl_set))
]
f.write(tabulate(first_table, headers = ["Category", "Total"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from tabulate import tabulate
b=OrderedDict()
b["Total agents"] = 45571
b["Total users"] = 90818
b["Users with agent"] = 70060
b["Users with invites"] = 81533
b["RUURL accounts"] = 81288

print tabulate(b.items(),headers = ["Category", "Total"])
Category              Total
------------------  -------
Total agents          45571
Total users           90818
Users with agent      70060
Users with invites    81533
RUURL accounts        81288
```

Comment: Where do you set `myordered_dict`?

Comment: But why `OrderedDict(a).items()`? That's the same as just using `a` directly!

Comment: Since OP wanted a dictionary..may be he wants to use it for a future use to access items

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables are not sorted (it defeats the purpose). Use an ordered datas tructure instead or try to handle it differently. For instance if your data comes from a database you can handle the ordering at the db level and just print out the data that is held in your output.